# C# Chart WinForms X Axis Mostrar tiempo en hh:mm:ss

Tags: c#, windows-forms

He buscado por todo Google y no encuentro la forma de hacer que los valores de un Chart sean por tiempo en segundos. No se si me explico. Por ejemplo, recibo 88 segundos para la Serie1, en el Gráfico debería aparecer 00:01:28 y en el label Y aparecerían el texto que yo quiera, en este caso añado un String representando las horas.

El tema, es que si le paso un número 88 funciona perfectamente, pero en el gráfico también pone 88 y querría que apareciera convertido a tiempo.

He intentado pasarlo a tiempo pero da error. En este ejemplo intento pasarlo a tiempo:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(total);
            Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
 chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("00:10 - 01:14",  ts);
```

Esto dará error, porque ts no lo entiende como variable aceptada tipo Int, double, float, etc. En cambio si pongo un numero entero lo muestra, pero esa no es la idea.

[image: grafico pasando un numero entero 88]

La idea es crear un control de tiempo de conexión de una app, desde que se conecta hasta que se desconecta, para así poder controlar los tiempos de conexión y tiempo de desconexión en otra serie.

También probé añadir esta lineal:

```
chart1.Series["Series1"].Label = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", (total / 60) / 60, (total / 60) % 60, total % 60);
```

Cierto que hace lo que quiero, pero me cambia todos los registros y pone la ultima hora en todos.

¿Alguna ayuda? Estoy desesperado, porque llevo más de una semana sin éxito